# How do I point my webapp url to my frontdoor url?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-waf

Currently my app is being hosted on MYAPP.azurewebsites.net and my frontdoor is on MYAPP.azurefd.net. I want all my incoming traffic to route to azureFd so I can gain the benefits of the waf policy I have set in place. Do I need to do this on the frontdoor configuration or is this another resource I have to utilize ?

Seriously wondering why this is not out of the box if I have Frontdoor and WAF policies on my app and resource group..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CNAME DNS record to map your domain to the azurefd domain, if you’re using the new standard/premium azure front door that’s currently still in preview the steps are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain

If you’re on “classic” azure front door use this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain

Comment: I'm not talking about a custom domain.. I'm just trying to have a domain provided by azure to redirect to the fd domain..

Answer (score -1):

The link provided was my backend host and could not be modified to be used as my fd dns. The valid solution would be to a redirect to the front door website. Either using Azure or hard coded in the web.config.

Comment: Hi, @RedLotus did you find any solution for this. I am having exactly the same issue and unable to find any solution